# oracle sql - select statement with multiple "case when" and check for contains text

Tags: sql, oracle, case, contains

I look for  a working example where I can use mutliple when case statment wihch check to verify if a specific text is contained:
e.g.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  NAME,
  (SELECT 
      (Case when Contains(Descr,"Test") Then "contains Test" 
        when Contains(Descr, "Other") Then "contains Other"
        Else "No Match" End) From DESCRIPTION
       where item_id = id
  ) as "Match"
  From Item
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? `Else "No Match"` is invalid SQL (unless you have a column that is named `No Match`). Also contains()` is an Oracle Full Text function and requires a different syntax then the one you are using. Are you **sure** you are using Oracle?

Comment: The contains operator seems not to  be known, I get an error

Comment: ok, which other function than "contains" can I use to look for a substring match?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Oracle string literals need to be surrounded in single quotes.

To find a sub-string match you can either use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT  ID,
        NAME,
        CASE WHEN Descr LIKE '%Test%'  THEN 'Contains Test'
             WHEN Descr LIKE '%Other%' THEN 'Contains Other'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    Item i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Description d
        ON i.id = d.item_id
```

or `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT  ID,
        NAME,
        CASE WHEN INSTR( Descr, 'Test' ) > 0  THEN 'Contains Test'
             WHEN INSTR( Descr, 'Other' ) > 0 THEN 'Contains Other'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    Item i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Description d
        ON i.id = d.item_id
```

or `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
SELECT  ID,
        NAME,
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( Descr, 'Test' )  THEN 'Contains Test'
             WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( Descr, 'Other' ) THEN 'Contains Other'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    Item i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Description d
        ON i.id = d.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INSTR function instead of Contains

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
with Item(id, name, descr) as
(
 select 'id1', 'name1', 'description containing Test' from dual union all
 select 'id2', 'name2', 'description containing Others' from dual union all
 select 'id3', 'name3', 'description containing nothing interesting' from dual
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    descr,
    case
        when instr(Descr, 'Test') != 0 then 'contains Test' 
        when instr(Descr, 'Other')!= 0 then 'contains Other'
        Else 'No Match'
    End as "Match"
From Item
```

Using [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651) is only one of the possible solutions; you may use [LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141), [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020), etc and different ways of writing the same query; I believe this is plain enough to be quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT 
  1,
  2,
  (SELECT 
      (
      Case 
        when     'contains Test' like  '%Test%'   
                              Then 'contains Test' 
        when     'contains Test' like  '%Other%'  
                              Then 'contains Other'
        Else 'No Match'
      End
      ) From dual
       where 1 = 1
  ) as "Match"
  From dual
```

you can use `like` func